# Conditionally add an extra parameter to an associative hash

Tags: ruby, vagrant, provisioning

I want to conditionally add an extra parameter to an associative hash.

The existing code looks like this:

```
:env => {
 "ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR" => "true",
 "ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING" => "#{config.host_key_checking}",
 # Ensure Ansible output isn't buffered so that we receive ouput
 # on a task-by-task basis.
 "PYTHONUNBUFFERED" => 1
},
```

I want to conditionally add another variable `"ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS" => "-o ForwardAgent=yes"` if `config.ssh.forward_agent` is `true`.

I could just copy paste, and create an if/else block but surely Ruby has something more elegant?

Comment: Python programmer here, so excuse my n00b question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like so:

```
   env = {
        "ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR" => "true",
        "ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING" => "#{config.host_key_checking}",
        # Ensure Ansible output isn't buffered so that we receive ouput
        # on a task-by-task basis.
        "PYTHONUNBUFFERED" => 1
    }

    env["ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS"] ="-o ForwardAgent=yes" if config.ssh.forward_agent

    command << {
      :env => env,
      :notify => [:stdout, :stderr],
      :workdir => @machine.env.root_path.to_s
    }
```

Not sure this is idiomatic Ruby but it worked for me.